# NumPy is faster than PyTorch for larger cross or outer products

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, pytorch, cross-product

I'm computing huge outer products between vectors of size `(50500,)` and found out that NumPy is (much?) faster than PyTorch while doing so.

Here are the tests:

```
# NumPy

In [64]: a = np.arange(50500) 
In [65]: b = a.copy()  

In [67]: %timeit np.outer(a, b) 
5.81 s ± 56.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

-------------

# PyTorch

In [73]: t1 = torch.arange(50500)
In [76]: t2 = t1.clone()

In [79]: %timeit torch.ger(t1, t2) 
7.73 s ± 143 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I'd ideally like to have the computation done in PyTorch. So, how can I speed things up for computing outer product in PyTorch for such huge vectors?

---

Note: I tried to move the tensors to GPU but I was treated with `MemoryError` because it needs around 19 GiB of space. So, I eventually have to do it on the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's really no way to specifically speed up torch's method of computing the outer product `torch.ger()` without a vast amount of effort.

**Explanation and Options**

The reason numpy function `np.outer()` is so fast is because it's written in C, which you can see here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7e3d558aeee5a8a5eae5ebb6aef03de892a92ebd/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1123
where the function uses operations from the `umath` C source code.

Pytorch's `torch.ger()` function is written in C++ here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7ce634ebc2943ff11d2ec727b7db83ab9758a6e0/aten/src/ATen/native/LinearAlgebra.cpp#L142 which makes it ever so slightly slower as you can see in your example.

Your options to "speed up computing outer product in PyTorch" would be to add a C implementation for outer product in pytorch's native code, or make your own outer product function while interfacing with C using something like Cython if you really don't want to use numpy (which wouldn't make much sense).

**P.S.**

Also just as an aside, using GPUs would only improve your parallel computation speed on the GPU which may not outweigh the cost of time required to transfer data between RAM and GPU memory.

Comment: Uh, why would you blame the difference on the language? The implementations are different, that's all that matters. Compiling the numpy function as C++ wouldn't change its speed.

Comment: @MarcGlisse you're completely right.  Sorry, as a python developer I tend to generalize that C++ implementations tend to be slower than your typical C implementation especially when used to optimize at the level of linear algebra computations (C++ implementations may be relying on less than optimal libraries).  For the question "how can i speed up outer products on pytorch", adding better C++ implementations could be stated

Answer (score 0):

A very nice solution is to combine both.

```
class LazyFrames(object):
    def __init__(self, frames):
        self._frames = frames

    def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        out = np.concatenate(self._frames, axis=0)
        if dtype is not None:
            out = out.astype(dtype)
        return out
```

`frames` might be just your pytorch tensors for instance.

This object ensures that common frames between the observations are only stored once. It exists purely to optimize memory usage which can be huge (e.g. DQN's 1M frames replay buffers). This object should only be converted to numpy array before being passed to the model.

Reference : https://github.com/Shmuma/ptan/blob/master/ptan/common/wrappers.py